# How to write to a text file without having repeating data on lines?

Tags: python

Okay so basically I'm trying to access a text file that contains data like this:

```
John 01
Steve 02
Adam 15
```

I'm accessing it, splitting the integers from each line and subtracting one from each one in the variable "days". Then after subtracting one from each line, I'm running an if statment to see if any line contains "0", if the line contains 0 it should remove the entire line (number and name), and then reprint the names with the new days - 1. My code below runs perfectly in console, and the names print out perfectly, as well as deleting, I'm just having trouble with the fact that each line is printing the last days value instead of it's own. For example:

```
Steve 14
Adam 14
```

Although Steve should be on 01, he took adam's 14. My code is attached below:

```
global days
global names
with open('tracker.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        days = line.strip()[-2:]
        names = line.strip()[:-3]
        days = int(days) - 1
        print(names +" "+str(days))

        if days == 0:
            f = open("tracker.txt","r")
            lines = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            f = open("tracker.txt","w")
            for line in lines:
                if line!=str(names)+ " 01" +"\n":
                    f.write(line[:-3]+ "" + str(days) + "\n")
            f.close()
    f.close()
```

Comment: You are using the same variables ``f`` and ``line`` in nested loop, this is prone to error. You're even changing ``f`` while you're iterating it!

Comment: Former answer posted as comment: I didn't dig a lot in your code, but you are assuming that days is written over two digits, which is a convoluted way to do the thing and very error prone.

Consider using split.

Untested example for inspiration. https://paste.ofcode.org/hdFrstgGtWMUCUpKXXCnaP

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul I would like to print back into the text document Steve 01 and Adam 14

Comment: @JohnS. i didn't get this line and then reprint the names with the new days - 1  , how steve have 14 there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do but let's try:

```
import os

# The file name of our source file and the temporary file where we keep
# our filtered data before copying back over source file
source_file_name = 'tracker.txt'
temporary_file_name = 'tracker_temp.txt'

# Opening the source file using a context manager
with open(source_file_name, mode='r') as source_file:
    # Opening our temporary file where we will be writing
    with open(temporary_file_name, mode='w') as temporary_file:
        # Reading each line of the source file
        for current_line in source_file:
            # Extracting the information from our source file
            line_splitted = current_line.split()
            current_name = line_splitted[0]
            current_days = int(line_splitted[1])

            # Computing and print the result
            future_days = current_days - 1
            print(current_name, future_days)

            # Writing the name and the computed value
            # to the temporary file
            if future_days != 0:
                output_line = "{} {:02}\n".format(current_name, future_days)
                temporary_file.write(output_line)

# After we went through all the data in the source file
# we replace our source file with our temporary file
os.replace(temporary_file_name, source_file_name)
```

So tell me. Is that what's you were trying to do? No? Well then give us more details!